# How to change the Contents of a msg box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

[image]

I have a form for creating a record, I also have a button on the top of the form for to return to a form called home. When the form is being viewed and half the information is put in and the home button is clicked an error pops up saying " you cannot add or change a record beacasue a related record is required in a table "Elements"." How do I Change what the content of the error message is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put checks in your button_click sub to circumvent -- check to make sure all fields are filled in, and if not, display your own message box followed by

```
 Exit Sub
```

That will short circuit the rest of the method so you should not get the standard message.

Comment: +1 for short-circuiting. To address your specific question, I don't think you can change that error message. Form validation is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a resource on error-handling in VBA: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

I'm not sure, however, if you can create a handler in VBA for standard program error messages.